# C++ OpenGL Old Data Remains In VBO after Modifying it with glMapBuffer()

Tags: c++, opengl

The code I would have to paste is too much. I have followed tutorials, however, when trying to implement them by myself nothing seems to work. I will paste the `glMapBuffer` routine below. Note that `vertex_type` and `render_target` are templeted parameters that allow users to set those enumerated values themselves.

An image of what is happening is.
[image]

Wich shows the square slowly being linearly translated towards the upper right corner of the screen by modifying the contents of the VBO.

```
bool modify_vertex_data(
  std::vector<vertex_2d_renderer_type<vertex_type> > &data,
  GLsizeiptr start_index) {

  if (!vertex_vbo_pointer_ || (start_index + data.size()) >
    static_cast<uint32_t>(vertex_count_)) {

    return false;
  }
  glBindBuffer(render_target, vertex_vbo_pointer_);
  vertex_2d_renderer_type<vertex_type> *vbo_data;
  vbo_data = reinterpret_cast<vertex_2d_renderer_type<vertex_type> *>(
    glMapBuffer(render_target, modify_access));

  memcpy(vbo_data, data.data(),
    data.size() * sizeof(vertex_2d_renderer_type<vertex_type>));

  return (glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR) && glUnmapBuffer(render_target);
}
```

The code that calls into this is:

```
void QtRenderer::paintGL() {
  //makeCurrent();
  count_++;

  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
  glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glViewport(0, 0, width(), height());
  glOrtho(0, width(), 0, height(), -1, 1);

  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glScissor(0, 0, width(), height());
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  glLoadIdentity();

  glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
  for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    data_[i].vertex_.x_ += 0.1;
    data_[i].vertex_.y_ += 0.1;
  }

  if (!renderer_2d_.modify_vertex_data(data_, 0)) {
    throw std::runtime_error("ERROR: Data Modification Error");
  }

  renderer_2d_.draw_vertex_data();
  glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
  swapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: How is this called? Is there a reason why you don't use `start_index`?

Comment: 'start_index' would allow them to modify a sub set of the data. For your first question I modified the post.

Comment: Ok thanks, but you still don't use `start_index`, even though that's not the problem because you pass zero to it, just making sure you're aware.

Comment: good point!!! Changed the memcpy to
memcpy(vbo_data + start_index, data.data(),
        data.size() * sizeof(vertex_2d_renderer_type<vertex_type>));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Actual Solution

After spending some time in chat with OP, looking at the code, I found the issue to be a redundant call to his OpenGL data initialization code. OP uses Qt's QGLWidget that provides a virtual method `QGLWidget::initializeGL` which is implicitly called by Qt as soon as the OpenGL context is ready to use. By overriding that method one can initialize persistent OpenGL objects like VBOs and such in a reliable way.

However in OP's code this method was also called *explicitly*, so the client side std::vector buffers for the vertex data got pushed another full copy of the vertex data, which then later got not modified, resulting in that apparent "residual" data.

Bringing the code back into proper QGLWidget semantics shape solved the issue.

#### Original Answer

<s>You're not clearing the framebuffer before drawing, so whatever was drawn before becomes the "background" on which you overdraw. OpenGL is *not a scenegraph* it's a drawing API. If you change data in a VBO it will not "magically" update the screen contents.</s>

Comment: If this is so then what does swapBuffers (http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qglwidget.html#swapBuffers) do?

Also if this is not what i need then what QGLWidget method do i need to use?

Comment: SwapBuffers makes what has been drawn in the back buffer appear in the front buffer. The exact way of implementing this is undefined: Either it's a buffer swap or a full copy or maybe even something different. However the contents of the back buffer after the swap are *undefined* and you **must** clean the back buffer in a double buffered framebuffer after the swap. `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` is your friend, use it first thing in the drawing code. *Never code based on asumptions!* You assumed swapping the buffers did something it doesn't, now it bite you.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, however in the example above I am using glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); in the method void QtRenderer::paintGL(). Is there anything else i am missing?

Comment: @MatthewHoggan: Oh, I didn't see it at first, sorry. What I said wrote still holds though. Well, I'd need to see your actual drawing calls then. BTW, OpenGL accumulates its errors, so you must actually call glGetError in a loop until it returns GL_NO_ERROR:

Comment: Link to the code is https://github.com/mehoggan/GlExtensions. The code base is small and should be easy to find your way. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MatthewHoggan: You should add the line `.*.swp` to your `.git/info/exclude` and remove that Vim swap file from the repo – BTW, nice to see a fellow Vim user.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29047/discussion-between-matthew-hoggan-and-datenwolf)